# Create a list inside an item of another list

Tags: flutter, list, dart, google-cloud-firestore, mapping

I have a list of teams to which the logged in user belongs to in my application. Within each team there is a list with the Uids of each team member **(teamMembersUid)**. There is also an empty list in which the information of each user **(teamMembers)** must be inserted.

**Objective:** I want to take the Uids of each user in teamMembersUid, extract their information from the database (Firebase firestore) and introduce it into teamMembers list. Here is the team model with the lists:

```
class TeamModel {
  String? uid;
  String? teamName;

  List<String>? teamMembersUid;
  List<UserModel>? teamMembers;
  List<String>? publicationsUid;
  List<String>? notifications;
  List<String>? instancesUid;

  TeamModel(
      {this.uid,
      this.teamName,
      this.teamMembersUid,
      this.teamMembers,
      this.instancesUid,
      this.notifications,
      this.publicationsUid});

  //receiving data from server
  factory TeamModel.fromMap(map) {
    return TeamModel(
      uid: map['uid'],
      teamName: map['teamName'],
      teamMembersUid: map['teamMembersUid'] is Iterable
          ? List.from(map['teamMembersUid'])
          : null,
      teamMembers:
          map['teamMembers'] is Iterable ? List.from(map['teamMembers']) : null,
      publicationsUid: map['publicationsUid'] is Iterable
          ? List.from(map['publicationsUid'])
          : null,
      notifications: map['notifications'] is Iterable
          ? List.from(map['notifications'])
          : null,
      instancesUid: map['instancesUid'] is Iterable
          ? List.from(map['instancesUid'])
          : null,
      //List.from(['teamMembersUid']), //castFrom adapts teamMembersUid to be a List
    );
  }
```

The following function (*getTeamsInfoWithUsers*) is responsible for:

1. **Create a list** with the teams to which the user belongs from firestore.
2. Extract the **Uids of each member** of each team.
3. **Get the information** from each user from firestore.
4. **Create a list** with the **information of each user of each team** and enter it in **teamMembers**.

   ````
       UserModel userData;
       List<TeamModel> retVal = [];
       try {
         //Create a list with the teams to which the user belongs from firestore
         final data = await _firestore
             .collection("teams")
             .where("teamMembersUid", arrayContains: userUid)
             .get();
         List<TeamModel> data_m =
             List.from(data.docs.map((doc) => TeamModel.fromMap(doc)));
         //Extract the Uids of each member of each team.
         retVal = data_m
             .map((team) {
               team.teamMembersUid!.map((userUid) async {
         //Get the information from each user from firestore.
                 userData = await getUserInfo(userUid);
         //Create a list with the information of each user of each team and enter it in teamMembers.
                 team.teamMembers!.add(userData);
               });
             })
             .cast<TeamModel>()
             .toList();
       } catch (e) {
         print(e);
       }
       return retVal;
     }```
   ````

**Problem:** The current user belongs to 4 teams and each team has 3 users. Debugging I put a breakpoint in *team.teamMembers!.add(userData);* line. Since there are 4 teams and each team has 3 users you should see the code stop on that line 12 times, 3 for each team. Instead, it only stops 3 times and doesn't seem to create the list of teamMembers in the data_m variable either. I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Error:
[Null error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRLl2.png)

Answer (score 0):

how about this

```
retVal = data_m
          .map((team) {
            team.teamMembersUid!.map((userUid) async {
              userData = await getUserInfo(userUid);
              team.teamMembers!.add(userData);
            }).toList();
          })
          .cast<TeamModel>()
          .toList();
```

[image]

VS

[image]

Comment: Hi @pmatatias I have been working with your answer but I am getting an error in another part of my code and I am unable to know if your way is correct. I will let you know when I solve it. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Hi @pmatatias I get an Null check error after cast<TeamModel>(). I have uploaded the picture at the end of the main question.

Comment: try to change from this  `}).cast<TeamModel>().toList();`   to this    `}).values.toList();`       

@carlosg56

Comment: It doesn´t recognize "values" in the code. What do you mean with "values"? @pmatatias